# Excel Row number of two column filter with different criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to get the matching row number in a table based on a multi-column criterium.

Below screenshot clarifies: the intent is to provide Date, Session (AM/PM), and Semester (1-6). Once the filter criterium is set, I should get the matching rownumber in the Table A:C.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
=MATCH(E2,A1:A10,0)&MATCH(F2,B1:B10,0)&MATCH(G2,C1:C10,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include what you've tried so far.

Comment: I had used =MATCH(E2,A1:A10,0)&MATCH(F2,B1:B10,0)&MATCH(G2,C1:C10,0)

Comment: The idea is to clarify and improve your own question directly as an edit to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a helper Col:D with the formula `D2` as `=A2&B2&C2` and copy down.

Then your lookup formula will be:

```
=MATCH(E2&F2&G2,D:D,0)
```

You may hide Col:D if you wish.

Comment: No problem! Could you accept the answer if it completely resolves the problem?